# Constructor injection for two mutually dependent classes

Tags: php, oop

A user fills in the form and submits it. Based on the input, an object `Organization` is hydrated. I want to separate communication with database from the actual object.

I thought of creating an `OrganizationMapper` that holds the methods for database communication (save, delete...). The organization class would get the `OrganizationMapper` through the constructor.

With these class definitions, however, I can't instantiate the classes because of their mutual dependence.

How else could I separate the database communication from `Organization` and put it into `OrganizationMapper`?

```
class Organization
{
    protected $id;
    protected $name;
    ... other properties ...
    public function __construct(OrganizationMapper $mapper)
    {
        $this->mapper = $mapper;
    }
    public function getId() {...}
    public function setId($id) {...}
    ... other methods ...
    public function saveToDb()
    {
        $this->mapper->save($this);
    }
```

The `OrganizationMapper` is

```
class OrganizationMapper
{
     public function __construct(Organization $organization)
     {
         $this->organization = $organization
     }

     ... other methods

     public function save($organization)
     {... the code to use the methods of Organization class to save the data to the database...}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And that's why circular dependencies are usually considered a bad thing.

---

Kidding aside, it seems to me that you do not actually need the constructor dependency in the `OrganizationMapper` class. From the looks of it, you're passing the `Organization` instance that you want to persist as a parameter into the mapper's `save()` method anyway and shouldn't need the instance attribute `$this->organization` in that class at all.

In general, I'd try to keep the `OrganizationMapper` **stateless**. Try to avoid storing an `Organization` instance as an instance attribute (*especially* if you actually use that same mapper instance for persisting multiple `Organization`s). Just do as you already did with the `save()` method and pass the `Organization` object as a method parameter.

---

Also, I would not associate the `Organization` class with the mapper. One could argue that this violates the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) as it's not the class' responsibility to persist itself. You could move this logic to the *calling* code and have the `Organization` class not know about the mapper *at all* (which is nice, because you completely eliminate the circular dependency between the two classes):

```
class Organization
{
    protected $id;
    protected $name;
    // <other properties here>

    // <getters and setters here>
}

class OrganizationMapper
{
    public function save(Organization $organization)
    {
        // save $organization to DB, somehow
    }
}

$organization = new Organization();
$organization->setName('Foobar International Inc.');

$mapper = new OrganizationMapper();
$mapper->save($organization);
```

Comment: thanks! you mentioned i don't need a constructor in the mapper class. when is it good to have that constructor? when the mapper has other methods that use the `Organization` object?

Answer (score 2):

To find a better way of seperating these two concerns, think about the purposes of your two objects:

- an *Organization* is there to give you access to all informations of an organization
- your *OrganizationMapper* is there to save a *Organization* object to database.

When you think about it like this, then there's a couple of questions, that rise up:

- Why does your *Organization* need a *saveToDb()* method? It's not it's job to save it?
- An instance of *OrganizationMapper* should be able to save any *Organization* in the database, so why do you pass it in twice? (once in the constructor, and once in the *save($organization)* method). In that case - what happens, if you pass a different organization to the constructor than to the save method?
- In your current example, how would you load an Organization from Database?

As alternative, I would suggest to remove *saveToDb()*  from *Organization* entirely, as it's not the job of the org to save itself to database. Additionally, I would remove the current Constructor from *OrganizationMapper*. In it's current design, there's little reason to pass the Organization to the constructor. 
Also, I would rename the OrganizationMapper to OrganizationRepository or OrganizationService. The primary purpose of that class is not to map SQL to Objects but to retrieve/save Organizations from/to DB. (Also, in OOP, classes should only follow the single responsibility pattern, so maybe the part mapping between SQL and Objects should happen in specializied class)

As a side note: generally, it's not a great idea, to give many ways to do exactly the same thing (e.g. saving an organization). This will probably just cause inconsistencies over time (consider that you will be adding some validation logic in the future, but might forget to also add it in the second place).

I hope this helps you :)

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I name your `Organization` type as `OrganizationEntity` in this post.

---

Pretty simply, **it's the other way around.**

The `OrganisationMapper` gets an `OrganisationEntity` object and persists it to wherever you want to, by means you can choose.

For your problem:

move the `saveToDb()` method from your `OrganisationEntity` to the `OrganisationMapper` and pass it an object to be saved.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why Mapper should do any opperations on DB? Mapper sounds like converting Entity (Organization) into something that can be an input for DB operation ie. [Query Object](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/queryObject.html).
You should rename your class into [DAO](http://bfy.tw/3pSG) or [Repository](http://bfy.tw/3pSK). It would be better name.

IMHO, the best idea would be to have:

1. Organization as an object that holds domain logic
2. OrganizationMapper should convert your domain object into some kind of query object
3. OrganizationDao should take Organization as an input param and use OrganizationMapper to convert it and do operation on DB.

BTW, why you are not using some kind of an ORM like Doctrine for example? It would make your life easier :)

Comment: thanks, sebastian! you mean the mapper in this case will act as a kind of mediator object, right? could you maybe make a quick code sample as an example? i'm actually using zf2 for this, but i wanted to understand how to do it without an ORM.

Comment: Mapper would translate your entity into something that can be easily send to DB.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that in php. Imagine if it would be posibble. Then instance of Organization would have a property OrganizationMapper, which would have a property Organization. So, property of a property of an instance of the class would be the instance itself! It is only possible in languages with pointers like c++. So, I see only 2 solutions here:

- Put the classes together
- Have a single link (maybe have 1 class that calls another while second doesn't call first.)

Comment: Strictly, you could emulate that behaviour with PHP too by using proxies. (e.g. a class that has a magic __call method and forwards every call to a delegate that can be set at a later time). In any case this is nothing that you would want to do ;)